# How could the equator remain frozen?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, climate

If possible, what would need to be different for earth's equator to freeze over and remain that way?

Here's what we know about the frozen ring:

- The temperature is below freezing for at least a few kilometers on land
- The equator has been frozen all year round for at least a few centuries
- Although the frozen ring may have always been there, it might also have appeared more recently due to geological, astrological or other sudden change in the earth's climate
- This earth may not look exactly like our own, but its climate in the other latitudes is ideally warm and habitable

Comment: This question has been asked several times: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/110431/30492 https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/73340/30492 https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/145923/30492 for example

Comment: Ah not sure how I missed those! thanks:) I voted to close my own question, not sure if there's a better approach

Comment: you can also delete it, since it has no answers